# How to contain catastrophic failure within a shared library plugin

Tags: c++, c, dll, crash

What can one reasonably do to try to contain catastrophic failures (such as crashes) within a shared library plugin written in C++, beyond catching all exceptions using `catch (...) { /* handle here */ }`?

My situation is a bit peculiar so let me describe it in detail.  The "plugins" [extend Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/Overview.html) (a programming language).  They must be compiled into shared libraries which export a number of C (not C++) functions all of which have the same signature (similar to `argc`, `argv`, etc.).   These functions can use a simple API to handle "arguments", return a value, or call back to Mathematica.  After the "plugin" is loaded, these C functions will be exposed as Mathematica functions.

My contribution here is a tool that takes the interface description of a C++ class and automatically generates these standard C functions to call class members. **I want to generate code to try to catch failures and report on them.**  So far the only protection I have is catching all exceptions.

Note 1: I am not interested in trying to run the plugin in a separate process for performance reasons.  The API that Mathematica provides give direct access to large numerical matrices within Mathematica.  I absolutely want to avoid copying these.  Mathematica also provides a different API for out-of-process plugins, which I do use when performance is not critical.

Note 2: I cannot change Mathematica itself, e.g. control how it loads shared libraries.

Note 3: I looked a bit at signal handlers, but I worry that it's not a good idea to set once since it will affect the host application, which I have no control over.  I only want to catch failures within the plugin itself, not other parts of the host.

---

I think this should be possible to some extent because MATLAB does it: if a MATLAB "plugin" (i.e. MEX file written in C) crashes, it won't immediately bring down the entire application.  Instead it shows an error like this:

[image]

Notice the "Attempt to Continue" button.  This is precisely the kind of thing I want to do: report some information about the problem (such as which plugin misbehaved, if this can be found out) and give a last chance to the user to try to save their work, while warning them about the potential consequences of continuing.

I expect some answers to be platform specific.  I'm interested in Windows, OS X and GNU/Linux.

Comment: Do you have some more context? the "plugin" architectures are very different.

Comment: On the Windows platform read about Structured Exceptions and how to handle them.  A starting point is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @EugeneSh. OK. The host application is Mathematica, so I don't control it. It's plugins are written in C (not C++).  They are compiled into shared libraries that export a number of functions, all having the same standard signature (similar to argv, argc). These functions can use a simple API to handle "arguments", return a value, or call back to Mathematica.  My contribution here is a tool that takes the interface description of a C++ class and automatically generates these standard C functions to call class members. I want to generate code to try to catch failures and report on them.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Note that the code I generate will be compiled into the shared library itself (not the host application which I can't modify).

Comment: @user3386109 I am not interested in running the "plugin" in a separate process.  The system I am working with already has a second "plugin interface" for separate-process plugins, so I can do that.  But that solution is too slow for some applications (in this case: accessing large numeric matrices within the host application, without copying).

Comment: @RichardCritten That would be a valid answer ... why don't you post it?

Comment: @Szabolcs, wrong assumptions lead to wrong conclusions. Read on shared memory.

Comment: @SergeyA I know about it, but it doesn't apply here. I can't change the host application. This question is specifically about the case when the plugin is not running in a separate process.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for the comment! I tried to fix the question as you suggested.

Comment: @Szabolcs Looks good, thanks. Unfortunately, I don't have an easy answer for the updated question.